# How to make ListView's height to grow after adding items to it?

Tags: android-listview

I have this xml in which I have a list view that I'm adding item to on a button click. The thing is that the ListViews height is not growing and I can only see the one item...

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".NewOrder">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:tag="Order Status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/field_label_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Status"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lstItems"></ListView>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:onClick="btnAddItemToList"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If it matters, the list view item has: 2 EditTexts, 1 TextView and a button so I use a custom adapter.

How can I make the list view height to grow accordingly ?

Answer (score 8):

```
private void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    Log.e("Listview Size ", "" + listView.getCount());
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {

        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

Call it when adapter is set.

Comment: @naltipar .Thanks for edit and actually it was by mistake as i am naive here.

Comment: Don't worry about that, everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution here: [Dynamically change the ListView height - Android](http://kk-brothers.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/dynamically-change-listview-height.html) that works for me (though I don't know if it's the best way because I thought it would be much simpler...).

Here is the code (in case the link won't do):

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Utility {
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
}
```